# How do I resolve a hostname from an IP address on Android on a LAN?

Tags: android, networking, hostname

I was able to do this on iOS using system apis, but not android.

Using InetAddress.getHostName() doesn't work for LAN addresses (only remote addresses).

I'm not above writing very low level UDP or TCP code or invoking command line tools. Most of the tools I'd use on linux or mac are not available via the CLI on android.

Any suggestions? I cannot find documentation for this at all.

Comment: do you have a DNS in your LAN?

Comment: I don't think there's a DNS server on the lan. I'm looking for a generic way that will work on all LANs. On iOS, I was able to resolve LAN hostnames with CFHostStartInfoResolution and CFHostGetNames.